# jvectormap marker color problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm trying to use jvectormap to create a map of the US with markers. I want these markers to either be red or blue and I would like to specify which color goes to which marker manually (not using any sort of scale or overly complicated data visualization function). Is there a way to do this? The new jvectormap's API is way too abstract for me to easily implement this.

I've tried using the old jvectormap but it appears it is buggy and doesn't show the markers in the correct locations.

Comment: Lets start with: what have you tried? Got an example, jsFiddle etc?

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/solarsaturn9/yhw3C/13/) of what I am looking to acheive. The way I am representing the data series right now is using a raw list of values for the data representation. Is there someway to include the value for the data series in the initial list of markers? This may be a simple javascript question as I am sort of new to javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/solarsaturn9/g7SKk/23/) is an example of two different types of markers based on a third element in the list of markers called *type*. I essentially created another array called colors used for the values in the data series representation. The loop right before the map is created iterates through the list of markers and pulls out the *type* and decides what the color value should be based on the *type*.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i].type == 'call-center') {
        colors[i] = 0;
    }
    else {
        colors[i] = 1;
    };
};
```

Similar setups can be achieved for different types if you add additional *if* statements.